# How Do I Create a Python / Django Egg?

Tags: python, django, egg

I have a Python program (with Django - does this matter?) that I want to 'bundle', if you like. How do I do this, in the same way one can create a .jar for Java?

Comment: Do you have a chicken? You need one to produce an egg. ;)

Comment: Who needs a chicken when you've got a Python ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use the [Python SetupTools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools).  You create a description file (setup.py) and then building and creating the egg is a one-line command (similar to Make).

There *was* a nice [presentation](http://ianbicking.org/docs/setuptools-presentation/) that would walk you through the details -- it's gone now.  So here's [another discussion](http://parijatmishra.wordpress.com/2008/10/08/python-packaging-setuptools-and-eggs/).

Comment: Hi. The Presentation link here is broken. Can you provide a new link with the steps to create a python egg. Is it possible to create a python egg for a whole python library ?

Answer (score 2):

[DjangoSkel](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/fez.djangoskel/) is the way to go.

Install DjangoSkel:

```
pip install DjangoSkel
```

Create skeleton for django egg:

```
paster create -t django_namespace_app
```

List available templates

```
paster create --list-templates
```